# SDL2 render texture visibly lags behind mouse

Tags: c++, windows, sdl, sdl-2

I'm using SDL2 on Windows (I've tested both Windows 7 and Windows 8). I was playing around with rendering a texture locked to the mouse coordinates to create a sort of "crosshair" effect.

It works, but the texture visibly lags behind the mouse which creates an awkward delay between mouse motion and the rendered updates. Honestly, the delay is very minor, but to someone who cares about absolute accuracy, it would drive the person insane.

My question is basically, is this normal? I'm guessing that the delay is due to the time it takes for Windows to deliver the event to SDL and then SDL to deliver the event to me. How can one achieve a locked "crosshair" effect via SDL?

My code for reference:

```
#include "SDL.h"

int main( int argc, char* args[] ) 
{ 
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ); 

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_LoadBMP("mouse.bmp");

    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

    bool isExiting = false;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    while(!isExiting)
    {
        SDL_Event e;
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&e))
        {
            if(e.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                isExiting = true;
                break;
            }
            else if(e.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION)
            {
                x = e.motion.x;
                y = e.motion.y;
            }
        }

        SDL_Rect destRect;
        destRect.h = 19;
        destRect.w = 19;
        destRect.x = x;
        destRect.y = y;

        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &destRect);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_Quit(); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Do you have the [Windows compositor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing_window_manager#Microsoft_Windows) enabled?  Does your main `while` loop always take ~16-17ms to execute?

Comment: @genpfault Compositing is enabled. I'll test when disabled. I haven't timed the loop yet, so I'll have to try that as well.

Comment: Your `SDL_Surface` will not be drawn centered around the mouse pos, change to `destRect.x = x - ( destRect.w / 2);
destRect.y = y - ( destRect.h / 2);`

Comment: @olevegard I appreciate the response, but that isn't the issue. There is a visible delay between the mouse moving and the rendering occurring. Adjusting the position does not affect that delay.

Comment: @JustinSkiles Yeah, I know. I just noticed it so I though I'd point it out.

Comment: Ouch, that is a slightly more complex situation. You need to use V-Sync to get that, and for that you will need multithreading. Time functions in SDL are a pain in the ass anyways.

Comment: @Zupoman SDL2 does allow me to create a renderer with the `SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC` flag, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Try adding a `SDL_Delay()` to throttle your main loop. If you hog the CPU the scheduler switches your program to a lower priority.

Answer (score 4):

While I cannot be sure why your loop lags, SDL has support for changing the mouse surface, as well as some other functions you may be interested in. It seems like you could put `SDL_CreateColorCursor(SDL_Surface* surface, int hot_x, int hot_y)` to good use. Here's a link to the wiki page on mouse support: http://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryMouse

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

In a project I'm working on, I do something like this:

(Outside the main game loop):

```
SDL_Texture* cursor = //blah;
SDL_Rect cursor_hitbox;
SDL_QueryTexture(cursor, NULL, NULL, &cursor_hitbox.w, &cursor_hitbox.h);
```

(In the main game loop):

```
SDL_GetMouseState(&cursor_hitbox.x, &cursor_hitbox.y);
```

While using this I haven't really noticed any input lag. Maybe it's just the event type?

Note that this is most likely not as efficient though, since you would be getting the mouse state every frame, instead of just when you move the mouse.